# Finding out whether a DLL in System32 is provided by Windows

Tags: windows, dll, system-restore

I have a program that iterates through the DLL dependencies of another program or DLL, and I'd like to ignore DLLs provided by Windows in this list.

Obviously, "exists in system32" is too weak a criterion, because several DLLs get installed there. Is there a way to find out (from a program) whether a DLL in the system32 directory came with the Windows installation and was not installed by a third-party installer?

(I suspect the System Restore API can be used for this, so tagging appropriately, but the answer might lie elsewhere)

Comment: Probably your best bet would be to look at the version resource.

Comment: Alternatively, all Windows DLLs should be digitally signed by Microsoft.  OTOH, there are Microsoft DLLs that don't ship with Windows - I *think* they are signed with a different cert but I'm not sure.